# Linq Complex OrderBy by Props attributes

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, attributes, sql-order-by

I have a class with some props tagged with some attributes. I want to display them on a specific order. So far I can put them in a order, but not on the order that I want.

Here is a simple example of the props with the attributes

```
[IncludeInEditor]
[IsInPk]
ID
[IncludeInEditor(IsReadOnlyOnModify=true)]
Name
[IncludeInEditor]
Address
[IncludeInEditor]
DOB


The order that I want is:
  1st - Props with IsInPk attribute
  2nd - Props with IncludeInEditor(IsReadOnlyOnModify=true)
  3rd - Props with IncludeInEditor
```

So far I got this with no sucess and not 100% done (still missing the IsReadOnlyOnModify=true part)

```
var properties =
item.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                            .OfType<IncludeInEditorAttribute>()
                            .Count() > 0)
                .Select (x => new 
                {
                    Property = x,
                    Attribute = (IsInPkAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(IsInPkAttribute), true) 
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute != null ? 1 : -1)
                .Select(x => x.Property)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: `.Count() > 0` to `.Any()` should be faster.

Comment: Good point Austin! I will re-think this, I have a lot of Count > 0 on my project. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `IComparer<T>` implementation to compare the attributes on each property:

```
public class AttributeComparer : IComparer<Attribute>
{
    public int Comparer(Attribute x, Attribute y)
    {
        if(x == null) return y == null ? 0 : -1;
        if(y == null) return 1;

        if(x is IsInPkAttribute) return (y is IsInPkAttribute) ? 0 : 1;
        else if(y is IsInPkAttribute) return -1;
        else
        {
            xa = (IncludeInEditorAttribute)x;
            ya = (IncludeInEditorAttribute)y;

            if(xa.IsReadOnlyOnModify == ya.IsReadOnlyOnModify) return 0;
            else return x.IsReadOnlyOnModify ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<IncludeInEditorAttribute>()
                .Any())
    .Select (x => new 
    {
        Property = x,
        Attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(IsInPkAttribute), true) ?? Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(IncludeInEditorAttribute, true))
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute, new AttributeComparer())
    .Select(x => x.Property)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Didn´t understand very well what you are trying to do... on the ELSE, your are casting both x & y to IncludeInEditorAttribute when sometimes Y can be IsInPkAttribute.

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR - Ok I missed a check for `y` which I've now added. Now the else block should only be reached if `x` and `y` are both non-null `IncludeInEditorAttribute`s.

Answer (score 0):

After the help of Lee, finally it´s working. The correct code is:

```
var properties =
                item.GetType().GetProperties()
                                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                            .OfType<IncludeInEditorAttribute>()
                                            .Any())
                                .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Property = x,
                                    Attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(IsInPkAttribute), true)
                                                    ?? Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(x, typeof(IncludeInEditorAttribute), true)
                                })
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute, new IncludeInEditorAttributeComparer())
                                .Select(x => x.Property)
                                .ToArray();
```

This code that Lee sent, I made a little change.

```
public class IncludeInEditorAttributeComparer : IComparer<Attribute>
    {
        public int Compare(Attribute x, Attribute y)
        {
            //In this case we can assume that
            //won´t have null values

            if (x is IsInPkAttribute && !(y is IsInPkAttribute))
                return -1;
            else if (y is IsInPkAttribute && !(x is IsInPkAttribute))
                return 1;
            else 
            { 
                bool xa = (x is IncludeInEditorAttribute ? (x as IncludeInEditorAttribute).IsReadOnlyOnModify : false);
                bool ya = (y is IncludeInEditorAttribute ? (y as IncludeInEditorAttribute).IsReadOnlyOnModify: false);

                if (xa && !ya)
                    return -1;
                else if (ya && !xa)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```